# safeseh gs on g++

Tags: visual-studio, g++, seh

I want to compile a c++ file. I'm following a tutorial, in this tutorial, the file is compiled with Visual Studio, and I don't have it. I want to do the same with g++. In the tutorial, use the /GS and /SafeSEH from VS. I want to know how compile my file with those flags with g++ compiler.

Sorry if my question is simple, I never used g++ before. And sorry for my english. Thank you.

Comment: What do those flags do?  Are they critical to the execution of your app?

Comment: On which operating system??? You might want to use `g++ -Wall -g` (to get all warnings and debugging information) even if they don't do exactly what visual studio is doing.

Answer (score 2):

So first things first:

- `/GS` actually performs "buffer security checks" which attempt to
  automatically detect buffer overflows and terminate your application
  before such overflows can be exploited.
- `/SAFESEH` embeds a list of all the structured exception handlers
  inside the executable so that the operating system can detect if
  unauthorized handlers have been installed in an attempt to hijack
  execution.

Now to answer your question: g++ implements a feature similar to /GS. You can compile your code with `-fstack-protector-all` to enable it. If you are curious you can look at the gcc manpages or use google for more details. g++ doesn't implement structured exception handling (it's a Microsoft extension) and so there's nothing similar to /SAFESEH in g++.

The good news are that unless the example you are working through is designed to demonstrate the extra protection /GS and /SAFESEH afford, compiling the code without them shouldn't be a problem at all. I'd be willing to bet that you can ignore those two options and just compile without them and things will be fine.

If you are interested in getting Visual Studio, you can get the free "Express" versions from Microsoft. Check out the website, here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

I hope this helps.

Comment: GCC 4.8 implements native win64 eexception handling. It's not compatible with VS generated code, and I doubt the safeseh flag has a counterpart.

Comment: GCC doesn't support the "structured exception handling" mechanism of Windows at least according to this: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/WindowsGCCImprovements

Comment: See http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2012-07/msg00512.html I said 4.8, it's still in development, and it uses win64 seh for C++ (and other language's) exceptions. The low-level C SEH is indeed still not fully implemented if I understand correctly.